# How can I set a shorcut key in VS code to run a .bat file in my working directory?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, finite-element-analysis

In my research I work with the finite element method, we use the solver from Abaqus which uses subroutines made with Fortran and I use vs code to edit them. So to run my codes I made a batch file that makes this process simpler (to avoid typing many instructions in the cmd).

In this image you can see the files in my working directory, it would save me a lot of time if I could set a shortcut to execute the principal.bat file and another one to terminate.bat directly from vs code: [image: batch files]
I appreciate any help, I've tried to set a task.json file for this purpose, but I am a little lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to type the batch file command to the terminal

Add this to your `settings.json`:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.callPrincipal",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": { "text": "principle.bat\u000D" }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.callTerminate",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": { "text": "terminate.bat\u000D" }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And then define 2 keybindings in `keybindings.json`

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+F1",  // or any other key combo
    "command": "multiCommand.callPrincipal"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+F2",  // or any other key combo
    "command": "multiCommand.callTerminate"
  }
```

You can add `when` clauses to limit the validity of the keybinding

---

**Edit**

It is not needed to use the `multi-command` extension when you only want 1 terminal command, you can define the argument to the keybinding

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+F1",  // or any other key combo
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "principle.bat\u000D" }
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+F2",  // or any other key combo
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "terminate.bat\u000D" }
  }
```

---

Or you can define 2 tasks to start the batch files and run them with **Terminal** | **Run Task...**.

If you designate one as the build task you can use the shortcut key for that.

I can't find a command that runs a named task, so it can be used in a keybinding.

Comment: Interesting. What does the `\u000D` after the command do?

Comment: @Tryer That is the `Enter` key

Comment: Thanks. Does this work if I need to run a shell file under a linux system? i.e., can I just say `./principle.sh\u000D`

Comment: @Tryer Yes, whatever the terminal accepts you can put in the `text` argument

Comment: Thank you  rioV8! I set 2 tasks  with this two args for each command:    "text": "cd \"${fileDirname}\"\u000D"   and   "text": "abaqus job=analisis user=2D.for\u000D"

Comment: @DiegoQuex if this solves your question you can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could add a debug configuration, then use <kbd>F5</kbd> to start that config.
The type `cppvsdbg` is unimportant here, as you can't (and don't want to) debug your batch file.

<kbd>Shift-F5</kbd> kills the batch process

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Start batch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "cmd.exe",
            "args": [
                "/c",
                "principal.bat"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false
        }
    ]
}
```